# Converting request params from DataTables with Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

I'm using Pyramid to handle ajax requests from [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/).  The request params have keys that are passed in like this:

`'columns[0][search]', 'columns[1][search]', 'columns[0][data]', 'columns[0][data]'`

Is there a way to tell pyramid (or another python library) to parse these request params into a nested dict so it looks more like:

```
{'columns': {
    '0': {'search': X, 'data': X}, 
    '1': {'search': X, 'data': X},
}}
```

Comment: is the first string the content from `request.params`?

Comment: @RafaelBarros Yeah, they are the keys from the request.params MultiDict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  It would be nice if I could return it as a set of nested MultiDicts so I could continue to use the `getone()` and `getall()` methods, but I don't seem to be able to instantiate the MultiDicts from pyramid.

```
def unflatten_multidict(multidict):
    d = {}
    for k in multidict.keys():
        m = re.match(r'^([^\[\]]+)((?:\[[^\[\]]+\])+)', k)
        if m:
            attr = m.group(1)
            lastd = d.setdefault(attr, {})
            subkeys = re.findall(r'\[([^\[\]]+)\]', m.group(2))
            for i, subkey in enumerate(subkeys):
                if i < len(subkeys) - 1:
                    lastd = lastd.setdefault(subkey, {})
                else:
                    lastd[subkey] = multidict.get(k)
        else:
            d[k] = multidict.get(k)

    return d
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a better solution for this?

Comment: No, haven't use datables for quite a few years now, so not sure if it's improved at all

Comment: You could use json.stringify and pass it as a string then turn into dictionary on the other end I found out.